# How can I create a Submission folder inside a SAMBA share?

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba

I have a Samba share running on CentOS 7. I am using ACL’s to control permissions for groups of users. I would like to be able to create a folder that a certain group has read/write/execute access to but inside that folder I would like a sub folder that group members can write into but not see inside of. This is the same idea as the `~/Public/Drop Box` folder on a Mac.

This idea works very well on a Mac server however we are replacing these with Linux boxes and its not that simple.

I have tried all combinations of ACL’s but not got anything to work well. The closest I have gotten was to set read/write/executeto the group submission folder and set the default permissions for the group to --- essentially making all files and folders created by users inside the submission folder inaccessible to other users but this is *far* from ideal?

Is there any way to do this on Linux and SAMBA or should I be having a rethink of this process?

Comment: Jake, thanks for the response. The issue is a ACL/permissions problem.  Its a bit out of the box but I like what you are suggesting and definitely something that I hadn't considered. How would you link the folder? is it a symbolic link? By "mount" are you talking about a SAMBA share? Unfortunately, this might still not be suitable as it could get very messy as I am talking about a share with up to 100 folders with 2 or 3 submission folders in each. I will give it a try as it looks like it may be an option.